# Change Android Package name without refractoring in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to be able to change the package name of our app without refactoring. The purpose is to create a build system for white-labelling apps (changing the logo and other minor details to hide our brand and emphasize the client's). It is current company logic. I know it is not officially supported, but I believe it is possible with small hacks or modifications to the build process.

Refactoring leaves a modification log of every file in the project, thus making those times meaningless. It is a possible solution, but I think not the best.

Everything works fine if change the package name and do not refactor, except only the the R class. On Eclipse, I copied the R file and renamed it (keeping it updated of course). In Android Studio, this is not possible because I can't find the R file and don't understand their build process.

I know this question will not be answerable by most Android devs, but is anyone has experience with Android Studio build process, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Gradle plugin has decoupled the "package name" from your application's unique identifier.

Previously, as is the case with the Ant build system used with Eclipse and the ADT plugin, your application identifier and the "package name" were one and the same, as defined by the `package` attribute in your manifest.

With the Gradle build system, you define an `applicationId` in your build.gradle in addition to the `package` attribute in your manifest. Most often the two are the same, but it doesn't have to be.

The `package` attribute in your manifest is what determines the Java package for your R class. If you keep this the same for all versions of your application, the R class import will not change.

What will change between the different variants of your application is the `applicationId` in your build.gradle. This is what the Play Store and Android devices use to uniquely identify your application.

For more information, see the post [ApplicationId versus PackageName](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename).